# Firebase: When deleting from storage AND database, should the storage deletion be in the onSuccessListener of the storage deletion?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

let's say I want to delete an entry from the Firebase Storage and also the meta data from the Firebase Database. Should I then delete them independently from each other like this:

```
@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

    StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
    imageRef.delete();

    mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
}
```

Or should I put the database deletion part into the onSuccessListener of the storage delete method?

```
@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

    StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
    imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
        }
    });

    mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
}
```

Comment: Or use Cloud Functions to have one automatically deleted when the other gets deleted.

Comment: I didn't even know about cloud functions :). I guess I have to look into it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever you need to delete an item and a reference across multiple services, you run the chance that one operation completes and the other fails. This *will* lead to corrupted data, so you'll need to figure out what is least harmful for your app:

1. Having an orphaned image, with no database node referring to it.
2. Having a database property pointing to an image that no longer exists.

If the orphaned image is the less harmful option for your app, delete the database node first and then delete the image in the completion handler. This is my preferred option, since my client application code does not need any special handling for the orphaned images.

If having a dangling reference in the database is least harmful, delete the file first and then update the database as Peter answered.

Whichever option you choose, you'll typically want to periodically run a maintenance process that cleans up the dangling references in the database, and/or the orphaned files in storage.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. I know its out of the scope of this question, but I don't want to open a seperate question for this: How do you save the key of the database entry to then delete it from  your app? How I do it right now: I have a field "String key" in my Upload class, but I don't pass it in the constructor, instead I use setKey() to set it when retrieving the images from Firebase. This way they don't show up in the database but only in the objects in my adapter. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Nevermind I have found an answer of yours where you do exactly that! Great!

Comment: How would a file in storage be corrupted if metadata in a separate db is deleted?

Comment: The file itself isn't corrupted. But if your "data model" is based on "I have a file in storage and a database reference pointing to it", then the rules of your data model are violated.

Answer (score 4):

```
  StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
    }
});
```

It is better to use the second way, since you know that the deletion will be successful then also delete the link of the image that is in the database.

Better than deleting from the database and maybe it did not delete from the storage, you will have a user without an image for example.