# Is it possible to group Realtime Database and Firestore updates?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say that I want to delete something from the Realtime Database and by deleting that, I am also forced to delete some entries from Firestore.

Is it possible to group these calls so that if one fails, everything fails? (something like multi-path update from Realtime Database)

Comment: Not sure why you were getting downvoted, so I counter-upvoted and answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no cross-product transactions in Firebase. The infrastructure of the services is simply too distinct to make that feasible. You'll have to make updates to each database separately and make sure your application code can handle "corrupt" data.

There was recently a question about deleting a file from Cloud Storage and updating the reference to that file from the Realtime Database. I'd recommend a similar approach as I gave there: [Firebase: When deleting from storage AND database, should the storage deletion be in the onSuccessListener of the storage deletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527169/firebase-when-deleting-from-storage-and-database-should-the-storage-deletion-b)

Note that running the cross-product updates in a reliable environment (at least more reliable than the average phone's network connection) is a great way to reduce the chances of interruptions during such an update. I'd recommend looking at Cloud Functions for performing the update: your client app calls Cloud Functions (either through a HTTP calls, or through a database queue), and the function then performs the update to both products.